# How download Android build support for Unity manually? (without unity hub)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a problem that does not allow me to compile for android, I have looked for solutions but it is always "untick and tick in unity hub" but I use the installer beacause unity hub uses much more internet, and I cannot download 15GB without having a crash that cancels the download
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsqeL.png)
and apparently I have the folder but the subfolders mentioned by unity do not exist, I used a beta and downloaded the latest LTS but I have the same problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qepcq.png)

Comment: `beacause unity hub uses much more internet` .. why would it use more than required? No it doesn't ^^ if you have the Hub it is way better to install this via the Hub so it gets properly registered

Comment: Alternatively download the according Unity installer and execute it again this way you can add the according modules individually ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the files before
[NDK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QaQ2gQQMAgjsH7kiMT2Jiw1allRSVrd6/view), [SDK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lVeWaMfOQNg7fqnu0CrUU_Zsw2qbjuTz/view) and [JDK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sfK4yjSfRHuTzeoZCyfbtWet8GlZaLiR/view)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. Check which android sdk/ndk supported by your unity version.
2. download from android google the necessary versions
3. In unity preferences change path to your downloaded sdk/ndk.

Same to openjdk